# percentile for datetime column python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, percentile

Is there a way to compute the percentile for a dataframe column with datetime format while still retaining the datetime format (Y-m-d H:M:S) and not converted to seconds for the percentile value?
example of the data with datetime format

```
df: 
0   2016-07-31 08:00:00
1   2016-07-30 14:30:00
2   2006-06-24 14:15:00
3   2016-07-15 08:15:45
4   2016-08-01 23:50:00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a built-in function `quantile` that can be used for that. Let

```
df = pd.Series(['2016-07-31 08:00:00', '2016-07-30 14:30:00', '2006-06-24 14:15:00', '2016-07-15 08:15:45', '2016-08-01 23:50:00'])
df
0   2016-07-31 08:00:00
1   2016-07-30 14:30:00
2   2006-06-24 14:15:00
3   2016-07-15 08:15:45
4   2016-08-01 23:50:00
```

then

```
>>> df.quantile(0.5)
Timestamp('2016-07-30 14:30:00')
```

See also the official documentation

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html

Answer (score 1):

`describe()` method on datetime column doesn't work the same way as it does on integer columns or float columns

So we can create our custom method to do the same:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime

base = datetime.now()
date_list = [base - timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, 20)]    
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Date': date_list})

df

                          Date
0   2017-08-17 21:32:54.044948
1   2017-08-16 21:32:54.044948
2   2017-08-15 21:32:54.044948
3   2017-08-14 21:32:54.044948

def describe_datetime(dataframe, column, percentiles=[i/10 for i in range(1,11)]):
    new_date = dataframe[column].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').sort_values().values
    length = len(new_date)
    for percentile in percentiles:
        print(percentile, ':', new_date[int(percentile * length)-1])

describe_datetime(df, 'Date')
```

output:

```
0.1 : 2017-07-30
0.2 : 2017-08-01
0.3 : 2017-08-03
0.4 : 2017-08-05
0.5 : 2017-08-07
0.6 : 2017-08-09
0.7 : 2017-08-11
0.8 : 2017-08-13
0.9 : 2017-08-15
1.0 : 2017-08-17
```

Comment: this approach does not work when I tried it. I also tried varying the percentile and values returned are the same.

Comment: @T-Jay I have created a custom method to do what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

After trying some code. I was a able to compute the percentile using the code below, I sorted the column and used its index to compute the percentile.
dataframe is 'df', column with datetime format is 'dates'

```
date_column = list(df.sort_values('dates')['dates'])
index = range(0,len(date_column)+1)
date_column[np.int((np.percentile(index, 50)))]
```